# How to remove application that is damaged or incomplete when it can't be found in the applications folder

Tags: applications

I have an app called Template on my computer with no icon.

[image]

When I click on it it says that "You can't open the application "Template.app" because it may be damaged or incomplete.".

[image]

I've looked in the application folder and searched in Finder trying to find this app to throw it in the trash, but I can't find it. It's not in the application folder or anywhere. So how can I get rid of it?!

I didn't use to have this application but I believe this happened after a system update long ago.

For information I'm running macOS Mojave v. 10.14.3.

Edit: Found this command in the terminal work.

`sqlite3 $(find /private/var/folders \( -name com.apple.dock.launchpad -a -user $USER \) 2> /dev/null)/db/db "DELETE FROM apps WHERE title='Template';" && killall Dock`